# I have tried but my program doesn't seem to work

Tags: javascript, html

I have created a system to translate english into pig latin, but it doesn't work. The problem is that the variable `fl` isn't showing. Does anyone know how to fix this?

```js
function piglatinify() {
  var word = document.getElementById("textbox").value;
  var fl = word.substr(1, 1);
  var wordwithoutfl = word.substr(2, 999);
  var piglatinword = wordwithoutfl.concat(fl);
  var piglatinword = piglatinword.concat("ay");
  document.write(piglatinword);
}
```

```html
<textarea id="textbox"></textarea><br>
<button onclick="piglatinify()">See it in pig latin...</button>
```

Comment: What is your question? Works fine for me.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean when you say the variable `fl` isn't "showing"?

Comment: The example you posted works fine for me.

Comment: if you look in the script tag, you see if we took the word hi and put in the the box, the program should put out "ihay" , h being the fl variable, but it shows "iay"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The length parameter of the substr() method is optional. Change this:

```
var wordwithoutfl = word.substr(2, 999);
```

to this:

```
var wordwithoutfl = word.substr(2);
```

Also, condense these lines:

```
var piglatinword = wordwithoutfl.concat(fl);
var piglatinword = piglatinword.concat("ay");
```

to this:

```
var piglatinword = wordwithoutfl + fl + "ay";
```

For two reasons: 1) This makes it so that you are not declaring the variable `piglatinword` twice, and 2) the "+" operator has better performance than the concat() method (see [this page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/concat) on the Mozilla Developer Network).

Answer (score 0):

A short way to do it would be:

```
    function piglatinify() {
      var word = document.getElementById("textbox").value;
      var piglatinword = word.substr(1) + word.substr(0, 1) + "ay";
      document.write(piglatinword);
    }
```

Also, remember that Javascript starts counting at 0, so to get the first letter, you need to do substr(0, 1). substr(1, 1) will get you the second letter.

word.substr(2, 999) can be changed to word.substr(2), as the length parameter is optional, but that would get you the string, minus the first 2 letters (qwerty => erty). Therefore, you would need to make it word.substr(1).